# ImageScience for Windows on Ruby 1.9

Tags: ruby, windows, rubygems

Has anyone have any success installing ImageScience on Ruby 1.9 for Windows?

Unfortunately, I am currently using Ruby 1.8 Windows for my development. I want to upgrade to Ruby 1.9 for the performance improvement. I was able to install almost all of the gems, but I haven't had any luck with ImageScience.

Rob Anderton had put in useful instruction for installation on 1.8, which I used. He seems to started using Mac since then :) (I am considering that, but in the meanwhile...)

http://thewebfellas.com/blog/2008/2/18/imagescience-on-windows-without-the-pain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `Devil` instead, it works in windows: http://banisterfiend.wordpress.com/2009/10/14/the-devil-image-library-for-ruby/

Comment: The problem is not Windows, is the RubyInline dependency. DevIL should work.

Comment: Thanks banister! I will check out DevIL

Comment: if it uses rubyinline and you're using 1.9 mingw, then you'll need this fork of rubyinline: http://github.com/rdp/rubyinline since the mainline one refuses my patches :)

Comment: banister, thanks again. I converted to DevIL and the code works great. The thumbnail were bit jagged on Windows (dev) so I was concerned initially, but worked great on Linux (production)